# xsql last version and support information

Tags: oracle, xsql

I am aware that XSQL is not supported anymore by Oracle (i.e. there is no release since 2004 or 2006). In other words, Oracle stopped supporting the XSQL many years back.

[XDK or XSQL Link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/xdk/index.html)

However, I couldn't see any official page confirming the same. Could you please point me to the correct URL where I can get some information?

Some of my applications were written using XSQL. We would like to upgrade it. However, we are not sure whether it has latest version or need to look for alternate technologies.

Kindly suggest alternate technologies to replace XSQL pages with some minimum changes. We don't want to rewrite all the functionalities again from scratch due to timeline or budget constraints.

Comment: The page you linked to refers to 'XSQL Servlet' in Oracle 12c, which is the current DBMS version. Are you talking about something different; or are you looking for a standalone download, separate from the DBMS release? What is prompting you to upgrade what you have - are you upgrading to 12c anyway?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for the standalone XDK version which has xsqlserializer jar files (XSQL servlet) and other xml parser jar files.